# Running a MS SQL server stored procedure with a mac in php using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in an instance of ms sql server, using php from a mac.

I have recently bought a mac book pro and seem to be having real problems achieving this.

I now have a connection established, which I know is working as if I change the password I get the message:

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)' in /Users/davidwhitwell/Sites/test/connect.php on line 6"
```

Correcting the password does not give me the error.

The script I am trying to run is:

```
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("CALL [finance].[get_all_company_names]");
    $sql->execute();
    $results = $sql->fetchAll();
    var_dump($results);
```

The result returns an empty array. I know data exists and that the correct permissions are in place to execute the procedure as I can do this directly with sql server management studio.

Comment: Can you run a general query with this connection?  I.e. Select * from some table;.  Is there any output from errorInfo: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: no I don't get anything returned even with a general select query

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you are not able to retrieve any data, even with a simple select query, I suggest adding some error handling to your script.

First, I would add some exception handling to your general pdo object.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This will throw an exception when your query fails.  Then wrap your execution in a try/catch statement

```
try {
  $sql = $pdo->prepare("CALL [finance].[get_all_company_names]");
  $sql->execute();
  $results = $sql->fetchAll();
  var_dump($results);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The sql and the pdo  objects you created also have a method called errorInfo, that will sometimes display an error.

```
if($sql->execute()) {
  $results = $sql->fetchAll();
}
else {
  $error_info = $dbh->errorInfo();
  print_r($error_info);
}
```

Some good resources include these page

- PDO Error Handling: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- PDOStatement::errorinfo: http://www.php.net/pdostatement.errorinfo

**EDIT**

I believe the ultimate is that stored procedures in MS SQL are called using `EXEC`

```
  $sql = $pdo->prepare("EXEC [finance].[get_all_company_names]");
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, the first suggestion returns: "An error ocuured: SQLSTATE[HY093]:Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound" There are no parameters for this stored procedure though

Comment: The 2nd suggestion returns a Fatel Error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'

Comment: Do you get this message when you do a simple select?

Comment: Thanks Robbert, I now have it working with the simple select, I believe the problem previously was that I wasn't specifying the scheme name for the table in the select statement, I also now have it working for the stored procedure and you were correct the issue was using call instead of exec. Thanks for your help.